# How to determine Snort rules source & destination IP and port

Tags: ids, snort, intrusion

How do you figure out Snort's source & destination IP and port if the question is so vague? For example:

Write a snort rule that detects a UK NI number sent from a client's web browser to a web server.

I understand how to write the regex to filter the NI number but it's the snort rule header that's tripping me. I'm also advised against using variables so I don't know if snort's default variables $HOME_NET and $EXTERNAL_NET are acceptable.

So far, my rule header looks like this:

```
alert tcp any [80,443] -> any [80,443]
```

Another question example is: "Write a snort rule that detects content sent from a mail server to any computer in a LAN..."

Is it even possible to write the rule without specifying the IP or port in the question?

Comment: "if the question is so vague?" -- what question? Is this a homework question? You've dropped all context. If this is homework, then this is more about what the asker is expecting than a security question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.